# Deploying django app on aws

Tags: python, django, apache

I'm quite new to python and I have developed a simple app using django which I want to deploy to aws. I followed the steps presented in [this][1]

[1]: https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/wikis/QuickConfigurationGuide.wiki link to install the same. I have installed apache and mod_wsgi. python version on aws is 2.7. The mod_wsgi that I have installed is: mod_wsgi-python27-3.2-6.11.amzn1.x86_64. I have added LoadModule directive in httpd.conf. Yet I get an error : ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi when I hit one of the end points of my app. Any clues around what might be the issue? I have tried looking up at existing solutions for this problem but none of them seems to be fixing the issue. Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

You can use many web server and app server to deploy Django app but **[here](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2017/01/deply-django-with-nginx.html)** in this tutorial all instruction are given step by step and there is a **[video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jN9iPaQzZbQ)** as well to guide through all the instruction to deploy the django app using `Nginx`, `vritualenv`, `gunicorn`.

Hope this is helpful for newbies.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed Django on the instance? It looks like Django is either not installed or is not being picked up.

If you you using a virtualenv, you'll need to add the path to it in your config file:

```
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com:/path/to/your/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Here is some more documentation from Django and mod_wsgi that may help:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/
https://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/develop/getting-started.html

Comment: Yes make sure the Django library is accessible by the user Apache is running under.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the most daunting tasks, especially if you want to deploy it with celery and migrations.

I suggest you use AWS Elastic Beanstalk, a managed to deploy your django app. You can use container commands to run migrations before each deployment too.

The following tutorial worked really well for me: https://www.trysudo.com/deploying-django-app-on-aws-using-elastic-beanstalk/

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy with nginx and gunicorn.
There is a great example to do this:
[How To Install and Configure Django with Postgres, Nginx, and Gunicorn](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn)

and one more:
[Setting up Django with Nginx, Gunicorn, virtualenv, supervisor ...](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/)

I hope this will help.